# Insert a new record if not exist and update if exist, laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there any way to insert a new record if doesn't exist and update the record if exist? the following is the code i using.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $this->validate($request,[
            'course_code'=>'required'
        ]);
    $batch = $request->batch;
    $students = User::select('student_id')->where('batch', $batch)->get();

    $course_codes = $inputs['course_code'];
    $data=[];
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        foreach ($course_codes as $course_code) {
        $data[]=[
            'batch' => $batch,
            'student_id' => $student->student_id,
            'semester' => $inputs['semester'],
            'course_code' => $course_code,
            "created_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), # \Datetime()
            "updated_at" => \Carbon\Carbon::now()  # \Datetime()
            ]; 
        }
    }    

    DB::table('assign_batches')->insert($data);
    return redirect('/admin/assign/batch/create')->with('message', 'A batch has been assigned to courses successfully!');
}
```

Here is my output when I inserted same records again. 
[image]
But I want one Student Id may have many Course Code but can not be duplicate. So I want to check if student has same course or courses then skip or update it and insert new records.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can also use sql Query :  

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$_table} ({$_columns}) VALUES {$_values} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {$updates} ";

DB::statement( $sql );

Answer (score 3):

Check `id` if exist then update otherwise insert

```
 if(isset($request->id)){
    DB::table('assign_batches')->where("id", $request->id)->update($data);
 }else {
    DB::table('assign_batches')->insert($data);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I wanted to check is there two records (student_id and course_code) are exist or not in a table row. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: take a hidden input for `id` which is unique in laravel template view and check as the the answer given

Comment: I think no need to check `student_id` with `course_code` with `$isDuplicate = DB::table('assign_batches')->where('student_id',$student->student_id)->where('course_code',$course_code)->count()`  and then check if `$isDuplicate > 0 ` to update otherwise insert.

Answer (score 1):

Use [firstOrCreate / firstOrNew](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

```
$students = User::firstOrNew(['student_id' => $request->student_id, 'course_code' => $request->course_code]);
$students->foo = $request->foo;
$students->save();
```

Comment: What is foo. Explain completely.

Comment: @SumitKumarGupta `foo` is just another column which is not related to firstOrNew

Answer (score 1):

for example if you have a table for every each user to vote once or update his vote;

```
//give the record to use

    $record = request('vote');
    //checkif there is a record for user in model
    $row = Uservoting::where('user_id',Auth->user()->id)->first;
    //if true
    if($row!==null){
        //update
        $row::update(['vote' => $record]);
        //if there isn't in model
    }else{
        //create a new row and insert the value
        $new_row = new Uservoting();
        $new_row->user_id = Auth->user()->id ;
        $new_row->vote = $record ;
        $new_row->vote();`

    }
```

hope this work:) {{--if you found any bug just tell me--}}